# firebase setCustomUserClaims execution doesn't end in emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set a custom claim to an existing user in the emulator with the following code:

```
exports.addAdmin = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims("ZZyxFu17eN8y6orw0tSQ8Y0vyPFS", { admin: true })
});
```

The logs tell me the the execution of the function started. `functions: Beginning execution of "addAdmin"` In the auth emulator I can see that the custom claim is successfully set to the user `{"admin":true}`. But the execution of the function doesn't end.

When I shutdown the emulator with CTRL+C I get the following logs
`functions: Waiting for all functions to finish...`. Then after some minutes: `functions: Functions emulator work queue did not empty before stopping ⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setCustomUserClaims()` does end but you are not terminating the function itself. To terminate a HTTP function, you must return back a response. Try:

```
exports.addAdmin = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims("ZZyxFu17eN8y6orw0tSQ8Y0vyPFS", { admin: true })

    return res.json({ message: "Claims updated" })
});
```

Checkout the documentation on [terminating Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=95s).